# Ubuntu 20.4 unable to locate a package which can be listed by pressing tab for autocomplete

Tags: apt, package-management

After doing `sudo apt update`, I start typing `sudo apt install pyqt` and then press the tab key twice to see what packages are available:

```
pyqi             pyqt5chart-dev   pyqt5.qsci-dev   pyqwt3d
pyqso            pyqt5-dev        pyqt5webengine   
pyqt5            pyqt5-dev-tools  pyqt-qwt         
pyqt5chart       pyqt5-examples   pyquery
```

And then, when I try installing with `sudo apt install pyqt5`, it says `E: Unable to locate package pyqt5`. Why list it then when I hit the tab key twice?

Comment: no, the 'Universe'  repository was already enabled in Software & Updates > Ubuntu Software when I encountered the bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you have discovered a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/+bug/1876495) with `apt` and `apt-get` auto-completion.

The `pyqt5` is a name of source code package for various pyqt5-related packages [which are compiled from it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/pyqt5).